# Congruence of elements implies congruence of norms for central simple algebras

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

I was reading Eichler's "Allgemeine Kongruenzklasseneinteilungen [...]", Crelle 1938 (one of the main historical references for strong approximation theorems), and I cannot understand one of the statements there. On page 231, just before Satz 1, he states that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are elements of a maximal order in a central simple algebra $A$ over a number field, $I$ is a double sided integral ideal of this order, and $\alpha \equiv \beta \pmod I$, then
$$
\operatorname{nr}(\alpha) \equiv \operatorname{nr}(\beta) \pmod I.
$$

I can understand this statement in some special cases, but could someone provide a **reference containing a proof**?

For a related example, in the maximal order $\mathbb{Z}[i] \subset \mathbb{Q}(i)$ we might take the ideal $I = (1+3i) \cdot \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then $2 + 3i = 1 + (1+3i)$ but $N_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}(2+3i) = 13 \notin 1 + (1+3i) \cdot \mathbb{Z}[i]$, as can be easily computed by checking norms. So it seems that the statement only holds for the reduced norm and not the absolute norm.

Comment: The point is that they are using the reduced norm here, which maps to the centre. Two-sided ideals of maximal orders are almost generated by ideals of the centre (above a prime ideal of the centre there exists a unique two-sided prime ideal of the maximal order).  Sorry I don't have time to elaborate more now.

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit on Aurel's comment: your example is not a central $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. It is $1$-dimensional over its centre, so the reduced norm is just the identity map. A reference for the result that Aurel is quoting is Reiner, Maximal Orders, Theorem 22.4.

Comment: I realise that my counter-example is not appropriate. Sorry about that! I'm not entirely sure, though, how to use the Aurel's quoted result. Does one apply this locally, using that the prime below is principal? I updated the question to simply ask for a reference/proof.